# Is it possible to add full-text-index-search to an existing image of sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

Currently I run the following command to create the sql server in docker, however this does not contain full-text-search.

docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=YourStrong@Passw0rd" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 --hostname sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried running a separate dockerfile. Tried to create new image out of that and run it. But the dockerfile I tried failed.

Comment: But I read that it should also be possible to extend the current image I already have. Only don’t know exactly how. Any links are also helping.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/161

Comment: Beware the final post in that issue link, it applies `USER root` in the Dockerfile to install the fts component but never reverts to `USER mssql`.